# "-o" like options for `elgrep`?

Tags: regular-expressions, grep

Sometimes I just want the matched result by regexp instead of the whole line, this seems possible via the `-o` option in `grep`

I discovered `elgrep` in emacs recently, which is fantastic! Any chance we can somehow include options like `-o` as in the usual grep (or equivalent ways via `elgrep`)? I tried some searches but cannot get it to work.

Comment: It is probably better to send a feature request like this directly to a the package maintainer.  In this instance, the package is developed on GitHub, so if you have an account you could either create a issue in the [repository](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/elgrep), or send [the maintainer](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/elgrep/blob/master/elgrep.el#L5) an email.

Comment: What @PhilipK. said. This isn't a question asking for an answer here. This is an enhancement request.

Comment: I made a feature request on your behalf: https://github.com/TobiasZawada/elgrep/issues/8

Answer (score 1):

This is [Issue #8 in the Elgrep Git repo](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/elgrep/issues/8). The fix is already in [Melpa](https://melpa.org/#/elgrep).

The context options in the Elgrep Menu have changed from

> Context Lines Before The Match: **Number of Lines:** 0
> Context Lines After The Match: **Number of Lines:** 0

to

> Context before match: **Line Boundary**: Count: 0
> Context after match: **Line Boundary**: Count: 0

Thereby, **Line** and **Boundary** are both active. You can choose character boundaries instead of line boundaries when you click on **Line**. The **Boundary** menu offers the same context settings as the previous version of Elgrep.

It would be very nice of you if you could test the new version of Elgrep on Melpa and give feedback at [Issue #8](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/elgrep/issues/8) or per E-Mail `i@tn-home.de`.

Notes:

- If you had followed the [advice](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/33844/philip-k) of [Philip K.](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/33844/philip-k) your problem would have been solved much faster.
- You could also try the new item *Copy raw contents* from the *Elgrep* menu of the `*elgrep*` buffer, i.e., the buffer with the search results. I think that this command is especially useful in combination with the character boundaries for the context. The raw contents of the `*elgrep*` buffer is copied to the `kill-ring`.